# Change the picture of toolstrip button everytime I click it in VB.Net

Tags: datagridview, tooltip, vb.net-2010

I'm working with VB.Net 2010.

I am trying to use a toolstrip button to fill my `datagridview` with all records including deleted ones. I use a flag column in SQL to set a row as a deleted one, instead of actually deleting it, and when I click it again I want the datagridview to be filled with not-deleted rows.

**Here is my question:**

How can I change the picture of my button every time I click it to show the user which view - all rows or just not-deleted rows - he or she is looking at? Or is there any way else to show the user this change?

Answer (score 0):

This example may give you an idea to work through your problem

1. Create two Function or method, one which shows all the records and the other that shows non deleted rows.
2. Call both the function or method according to the condition and set the image.

**Write the code in click event of button.**

```
       Dim GetNonDeletedDataTable As DataTable = GetNonDeletedDataTable()
       Dim GetFullDataTable As DataTable = GetFullDataTable()

      '
      ' Fill in the data grid When Imange shows ShowFullRecImg.bmp.           
      if(GetNonDeletedDataTable.Rows.Count<>0 And this.toolStripButton1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\ShowFullRecImg.bmp"))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = GetFullDataTable()
        this.toolStripButton1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\ShowNonDeletedRecImg.bmp")
      End if

      '
      ' Fill in the data grid When Imange shows ShowNonDeletedRecImg.bmp.
      if(GetFullDataTable.Rows.Count<>0 And this.toolStripButton1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\ShowNonDeletedRecImg.bmp"))
      DataGridView1.DataSource = GetFullDataTable()
      this.toolStripButton1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("c:\\ShowFullRecImg.bmp")
      End if
```

**First Function as `GetFullDataTable()`**

```
    Private Function GetFullDataTable() As DataTable
    '
    ' This Function needs to build the data table which contains both deleted and non deleted rows.
    Return New DataTable()
    End Function
```

**Second Function as `GetNonDeletedDataTable()`**

```
    Private Function GetNonDeletedDataTable() As DataTable
    '
    ' This Function needs to build the data table which contains non deleted rows.
    Return New DataTable()
    End Function
```

Comment: @Zoya Y.G. did this example help you? if so Then please accept and upvote.